# Simulating a timeseries in dplyr instead of using a for loop

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So, while `lag` and `lead` in dplyr are great, I want to simulate a timeseries of something like population growth.  My old school code would look something like:

```
tdf <- data.frame(time=1:5, pop=50)
for(i in 2:5){
  tdf$pop[i] = 1.1*tdf$pop[i-1]
}
```

which produces

```
  time    pop
1    1 50.000
2    2 55.000
3    3 60.500
4    4 66.550
5    5 73.205
```

I feel like there has to be a `dplyr` or `tidyverse` way to do this (as much as I love my for loop).

But, something like

```
tdf <- data.frame(time=1:5, pop=50) %>%
  mutate(pop = 1.1*lag(pop))
```

which would have been my first guess just produces

```
  time pop
1    1  NA
2    2  55
3    3  55
4    4  55
5    5  55
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.... what is it?

Note - this is a trivial example - my real examples use multiple parameters, many of which are time-varying (I'm simulating forecasts under different GCM scenarios), so, the tidyverse is proving to be a powerful tool in bringing my simulations together.

Comment: I think the philosophy of dplyr is pretty rooted in data manipulation, not data creation.  There probably is a dplyr way to do this somehow, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I do a fair amount of dynamic modeling also of complex systems where rate of change depends on other parameters that also vary over time with other parameters that also vary with time... Sound similar to your case. While simple dynamics can be vectorised in R, once things get complex loops become the only realistic solution. But then speed can become very slow if you try to do these loops in R. My solution is typically to stick with loops, but do the intensive looping stuff in RCpp. R is great, but its not always the best for everything. Fortunately Rcpp takes the pain out of linking C++ to R

Comment: For this case, specifically, the issue is that `lag()` and `lead()` don't operate row-by-row, but just shift the index of the column by one.  The new `pop` is just `1.1*c(NA, tdf$pop[-length(pop)]`.

Comment: I hear you, dww, but, in teaching, one can only go so far and cover so many topics! I think if I introduced RCpp, there might be a riot... Ha!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Reduce` (or its purrr variants, if you like) is what you want for cumulative functions that don't already have a `cum*` version written:

```
data.frame(time = 1:5, pop = 50) %>%
    mutate(pop = Reduce(function(x, y){x * 1.1}, pop, accumulate = TRUE))

##   time    pop
## 1    1 50.000
## 2    2 55.000
## 3    3 60.500
## 4    4 66.550
## 5    5 73.205
```

or with purrr,

```
data.frame(time = 1:5, pop = 50) %>%
    mutate(pop = accumulate(pop, ~.x * 1.1))

##   time    pop
## 1    1 50.000
## 2    2 55.000
## 3    3 60.500
## 4    4 66.550
## 5    5 73.205
```

Comment: Yes! Although - one question (which is my lack of familiarity with purrr) - if I had multiple timevarying columns - say, gr as growth rate, how would that pass through to `accumulate`?

Comment: Assuming you're calculating each individually, use one of the other forms of `mutate`, i.e. `mutate_all`, `mutate_if`, or `mutate_at`, wrap the function in `funs` and replace the column name with `.`, e.g. `mutate_all(funs(accumulate(., ~.x * 1.1)))`

Comment: It's disturbing to me that only the first element of `pop` is needed yet the entire column is set to 50 and replaced. `pop` could just as well be `c(50, 51, -32, 1, 2)` or any other vector starting with 50 and you'd get the same result.

Comment: @jtr13 Yep. It's actually a reasonably efficient approach (absent vectorization), though, because adding the whole column correctly preallocates memory for `Reduce`'s loop. Bigger picture, `Reduce` can handle binary functions, where one variable will be the inherited value, and the other (`y` above) will be the iterated value in the vector. The OP just didn't need that second variable here.

Comment: Is there another function in `Rcpp` more faster than `accumulate2` in `purrr`?

Comment: @OmarAbdEl-Naser Rcpp lets you run C++ from R, but doesn't contain lots of precompiled functions. So if you want to translate `accumulate2` and your lambda to C++, it's likely faster. Writing it will not be.

Answer (score 5):

If the starting value of `pop` is, say, 50, then `pop = 50 * 1.1^(0:4)` will give you the next four values. With your code, you could do:

```
data.frame(time=1:5, pop=50) %>%
  mutate(pop = pop * 1.1^(1:n() - 1))
```

Or,

```
base = 50

data.frame(time=1:5) %>%
  mutate(pop = base * 1.1^(1:n()-1))
```

Comment: that's nice, but the case where you can get an exact analytical solution is essentially trivial ... (yes, this is the example the OP gave, so it is a legitimate solution - just, I think, not that useful)

Answer (score 5):

Purrr's accumulate function can handle time-varying indices, if you pass them 
to your simulation function as a list with all the parameters in it. However, it takes a bit of wrangling to get this working correctly. The trick here is that accumulate() can work on list as well as vector columns. You can use the `tidyr` function nest() to group columns into a list vector containing the current population state and parameters, then use accumulate() on the resulting list column. This is a bit complicated to explain, so I've included a demo, simulating logistic growth with either a constant growth rate or a time-varying stochastic growth rate. I also included an example of how to use this to simulate multiple replicates for a given model using dpylr+purrr+tidyr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# Declare the population growth function. Note: the first two arguments
# have to be .x (the prior vector of populations and parameters) and .y,
# the current parameter value and population vector. 
# This example function is a Ricker population growth model. 
logistic_growth = function(.x, .y, growth, comp) {
  pop = .x$pop[1]
  growth = .y$growth[1]
  comp  = .y$comp[1]
  # Note: this uses the state from .x, and the parameter values from .y.
  # The first observation will use the first entry in the vector for .x and .y
  new_pop = pop*exp(growth - pop*comp)
  .y$pop[1] = new_pop
  return(.y)
}

# Starting parameters the number of time steps to simulate, initial population size,
# and ecological parameters (growth rate and intraspecific competition rate)
n_steps  = 100
pop_init = 1
growth = 0.5
comp = 0.05

#First test: fixed growth rates
test1 = data_frame(time = 1:n_steps,pop = pop_init, 
                   growth=growth,comp =comp)


# here, the combination of nest() and group_by() split the data into individual 
# time points and then groups all parameters into a new vector called state.
# ungroup() removes the grouping structure, then accumulate runs the function
#on the vector of states. Finally unnest transforms it all back to a
#data frame
out1 = test1 %>%
  group_by(time)%>%
  nest(pop, growth, comp,.key = state)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(
    state = accumulate(state,logistic_growth))%>%
  unnest()

# This is the same example, except I drew the growth rates from a normal distribution
# with a mean equal to the mean growth rate and a std. dev. of 0.1
test2 = data_frame(time = 1:n_steps,pop = pop_init, 
                   growth=rnorm(n_steps, growth,0.1),comp=comp)

out2 = test2 %>%
  group_by(time)%>%
  nest(pop, growth, comp,.key = state)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(
    state = accumulate(state,logistic_growth))%>%
  unnest()

# This demostrates how to use this approach to simulate replicates using dplyr
# Note the crossing function creates all combinations of its input values
test3 = crossing(rep = 1:10, time = 1:n_steps,pop = pop_init, comp=comp) %>%
  mutate(growth=rnorm(n_steps*10, growth,0.1))

out3 = test3 %>%
  group_by(rep)%>%
  group_by(rep,time)%>%
  nest(pop, growth, comp,.key = state)%>%
  group_by(rep)%>%
  mutate(
    state = accumulate(state,logistic_growth))%>%
  unnest()

print(qplot(time, pop, data=out1)+
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(data= out2, col="red")+
        geom_line(data=out2, col="red")+
        geom_point(data=out3, col="red", alpha=0.1)+
        geom_line(data=out3, col="red", alpha=0.1,aes(group=rep)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `dplyr` is running this as a set of vector operations rather than evaluating the term one at a time. Here, `1.1*lag(pop)` is being interpreted as "calculate the lagged values for all of pop, then multiple them all by 1.1". Since you `set pop=50` lagged values for all the steps were 50.

`dplyr` does have some helper functions for sequential evaluation; the standard function `cumsum`, `cumprod`, etc. work, and a few new ones (see `?cummean`) all work within `dplyr`. In your example, you could simulate the model with:

```
tdf <- data.frame(time=1:5, pop=50, growth_rate = c(1, rep(1.1,times=4)) %>%
    mutate(pop = pop*cumprod(growth_rate))


time    pop     growth_rate
1       50.000  1.0
2       55.000  1.1
3       60.500  1.1
4       66.550  1.1
5       73.205  1.1
```

Note that I added growth rate as a column here, and I set the first growth rate to 1. You could also specify it like this:

```
tdf <- data.frame(time=1:5, pop=50, growth_rate = 1.1) %>%
    mutate(pop = pop*cumprod(lead(growth_rate,default=1))
```

This makes it explicit that the growth rate column refers to the rate of growth in the current time step from the previous one.

There are limits to how many different simulations you can do this way, but it should be feasible to construct a lot of discrete-time ecological models using some combination of the cumulative functions and parameters specified in columns.

Comment: Hrm - this is close, as one could incorporate other timevarying parameters in cumprod. But still not quite flexible for my end goal.

Comment: True, it's not that flexible. Also, after thinking on it, I realized it would be very difficult (maybe impossible) to add interactions, density-dependence, or nonlinear terms this way. I've used dplyr this way for simulating random walks, but that doesn't require interacting terms, since most of it is generating independent variables and aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

What about the map functions, i.e.

```
tdf <- data_frame(time=1:5)
tdf %>% mutate(pop = map_dbl(.x = tdf$time, .f = (function(x) 50*1.1^x)))
```

Comment: That's all well and good for a continuous time approximation, but, what if there are time varying parameters? Although I like that purrr is part of the solution here!

Comment: If you can capture the time varying aspect in a function you can easily apply the same logic or perhaps nest map functions.